# Bootstrap 3 modal shows a transparent background

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I created a simple HTML with bootstrap 3.2 :

```
<body>
    <div>
        <a class="btn" href="#frmLogin" data-toggle="modal">login</a>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="frmLogin" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content>">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <a class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                    <h3 id="modalTitle">Login</h3>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

but the modal does not show correctly.

fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/jsmLxhv9/1/

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/jsmLxhv9/2/

Comment: Thank you so much , It worked , however I did not understand what made my code not to work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<body>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Login
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 12):

I'm a little late to the party here, but I had the same issue, which lead me to this post.  The issue with the posted code is that

```
<div class="modal-content>">
```

needs to be

```
<div class="modal-content">
```

Other than that, it works fine.  Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/hjqo17dq/

Comment: I don't see the difference.

Comment: There's an extra > inside the quotes on the first one.

Comment: Thanks!  I did not see that.  I made my modal work too.